# show single row to multiple columns in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I have one table like below

```
ID | Data | IDS
1  |  s1  |  4
2  |  s2  |  4
3  |  s3  |  4
4  |  d1  |  5
5  |  d2  |  5
```

I need Data to display column like USING IDS COLUMN DATA

```
Data1 | Data2
s1    |  d1
s2    |  d2
s2    |  null
```

Please suggest on this requirement

Comment: I think there is a typo in your question in the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()` and `group by`:

```
select max(case when ids = 4 then data end) as col1,
       max(case when ids = 5 then data end) as col2
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by ids order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```